# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

- I have a react code
- this code renders various panels in the UI.
- when I click a tag, this function is called sportsCornerPanel()
- but I am getting the Uncaught TypeError how to fix it
- providing snippet code below.
- whole code you can see it in the fiddle

**code snippet**

```
    sportsCornerPanel() {
        debugger;

        console.log("sportsCornerPanel"
        console.log("this.props.sportsPanelState.size-->" + this.props);

        if (this.props.sportsPanelState.size === 'hidden') {

            if (!this.props.sportsPanelState.visible) {
                this.props.dispatch(sportsOpenPanel());
            } else {
                this.props.dispatch(sportsClosePanel());
            }
        }
    }


    render() {


        let sportsContent, leftNavLink;

        if (this.props.sports-layout !== 'small') {
            console.log("SportsBox---page loads at bigger size");
            console.log("SportsBox---page loads at ipad size");
            sportsContent = <SportsBox className="sports-header"/>;
        } else {
            if (this.props.sportsPanelState.visible) {
                console.log("sportsPanelState--when it becomes small--around ipad width");

                sportsContent = <SportsBox className="sports-nav"/>;
                leftNavLink = <a onClick={this.sportsCornerPanel} href="javascript:;" className="header-navLink active"></a>;
            } else {
                if (this.props.sports.active) {

                    console.log("SportsBox");

                    sportsContent = <SportsBox className="sports-nav"/>;
                } else {

                    console.log("leftNavLink--when it becomes small--around ipad width");

                    leftNavLink = <a onClick={this.sportsCornerPanel} href="javascript:;" className="header-navLink"></a>;
                }
            }
        }


output

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Since you are not using `React.createClass` in class methods `this` doesn't refers to the component instance, so you should bind it manually. There are several ways:

**1. Manually bind `this` in class constructor**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.sportsCornerPanel= this.sportsCornerPanel.bind(this);
}
```

**2. Use ES7 Property initializers with arrow function**

```
sportsCornerPanel = () => {
    debugger;

    console.log("sportsCornerPanel"
    console.log("this.props.sportsPanelState.size-->" + this.props);

    if (this.props.sportsPanelState.size === 'hidden') {

        if (!this.props.sportsPanelState.visible) {
            this.props.dispatch(sportsOpenPanel());
        } else {
            this.props.dispatch(sportsClosePanel());
        }
    }
}
```

**3. Bind `this` at call-site**

In `render()` method:

```
    let sportsContent, leftNavLink;

    if (this.props.sports-layout !== 'small') {
        console.log("SportsBox---page loads at bigger size");
        console.log("SportsBox---page loads at ipad size");
        sportsContent = <SportsBox className="sports-header"/>;
    } else {
        if (this.props.sportsPanelState.visible) {
            console.log("sportsPanelState--when it becomes small--around ipad width");

            sportsContent = <SportsBox className="sports-nav"/>;
            leftNavLink = <a onClick={this.sportsCornerPanel.bind(this)} href="javascript:;" className="header-navLink active"></a>;
        } else {
            if (this.props.sports.active) {

                console.log("SportsBox");

                sportsContent = <SportsBox className="sports-nav"/>;
            } else {

                console.log("leftNavLink--when it becomes small--around ipad width");

                leftNavLink = <a onClick={this.sportsCornerPanel.bind(this)} href="javascript:;" className="header-navLink"></a>;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's common issue when using `extends React.Component` instead `React.createClass()`.

Comment: To debug, simply `console.log(this)` in the beginning of class method. If it outputs `null` or `undefined`, so this is the problem.

Comment: Thanks and how arrow functions will fix it??

Comment: Arrow function has same lexical `this` as code that surrounds it, so we get desired result because of property initializers scope.

Comment: Arrow function is the best one

Answer (score 1):

Declare a local variable in constructor for capturing context.

I faced the same issue while using `class className extends React.Component` instead of `createClass()`. Create a variable in constructor to fix this.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    self = this;
}
```

Use `self.props` instead of `this.props` everywhere!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be missing a `getDefaultProps` method on your React component. You might consider something generic like this, just to nullify the error and see what else is up:

`getDefaultProps () { return {}; }`

Comment: The fact that the error is saying that the issue is with the react component itself and not necessarily its props makes me think that the *props* aren't the issue - have you tested this solution to see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

## binding the method in constructor worked absolutely fine.

```
class Example extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.homeButtonClicked= this.homeButtonClicked.bind(this);
  }
}
```