# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my child component that needs to pass data up to its parent.

```
class Sidebar extends React.Component {

  getUserInput(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let value = document.getElementById('input-button').value;
    console.log(value);
    this.props.handleSubmit(value);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <input type="text" id="input-button" placeholder="YGUID" />

            <button type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-icons" onClick={this.getUserInput} />

      </div>
    );

  }
}

Sidebar.propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: React.PropTypes.func
};
```

This is where the parent is calling handleSubmit.

```
......
handleSubmit(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
  render(){
    return(
        <div className="col-md-2 left-pane">
          <Sidebar handleSubmit= {this.handleSubmit}/>
        </div>

    );
  }
```

I get the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: What does `console.log(this)` in the `getUserInput` function return? please this [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303490/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-props-of-null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.getUserInput` function passed to the `Sidebar` props is not bound to the correct context (`this`) when it is called. You can for example [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) it:

```
<Sidebar handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
```

There are also other options how to sovle this. For example using arrow functions which has lexical `this`, binding methods in constructor or using class properties to define methods with arrow functions (ES7).